# Change Faenza-Radiance default empathy icons

Tags: 11.10, themes, icons

I really like Faenza icons and I use Radiance as GTK theme, but the problem is Faenza-Radiance icons for empathy are really annoying! I want to change empathy icons of Faenza-Radiance to look like Faenza-Dark's icons

Faenza-Radiance:

[image: Faenza-Radiance]

Faenza-Dark:

[image: Faenza-Dark]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well that's easy.

Open up Nautilus/PCmanfm/Marlin/Thunar and go to `/usr/share/icons/Faenza-Dark/status/` or `/home/.icons/Faenza-Dark/status/`

There you'll see different icon sizes 16, 32, 48, etc, inside locate these files:

1. empathy-available.png
2. empathy-away.png
3. empathy-busy.png
4. empathy-extended-away.png
5. empathy-invisible.png
6. empathy-offline.png

And copy the files from the Faenza-Dark folder over the Faenza-Radiance folder, overwritting them in the process, you need root permissions to move them should they be in `/usr/share/`, open up a terminal and type `gksu nautilus` that will spawn another window with root permissions so you can copy the files between folders located in `/` such as `/usr/`.

There is no need to use this if the icons are in your home folder and ***DO NOT USE*** `sudo nautilus`.

Copy the desired sizes, and done that should do it.

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple symlinking will do the trick as well:

`sudo ln -s /usr/share/icons/Faenza-Dark/status/22/empathy* /usr/share/icons/Faenza-Radiance/status/22/`

You may need to `mkdir` for other icon size i.e. 16 and 24 from what I see in Faenza-Dark status icons and repeat the process replacing 22 with other icon size.

May be somebody with better bash skills would narrow down the process.